# What could be wrong with this plane?

Tags: troubleshooting, electronics

The story of how it broke;

I have a plane that I am/was building/fixing, and I was successfully able to make it fly...[very shortly](https://drive.google.com/file/d/132Cut0K8STlXcEK03IgWhFeFjuN77aGu/view?usp=sharing). Yes, I know that I launched it really bad and that I should've done a dozen things differently, but that's besides the point right now. After that crash, it was completely fine (except for the prop). I put on a new prop and tried again, with pretty much the same results, but I did get a bit higher and I had help launching it. After a second crash, I didn't have any more props of that size, and my 9050 props had a different hole size.

So I drilled some bigger holes in the 9050 props and put one on the next day, but the receiver wouldn't turn on. I figured I must've plugged something in wrong or left it in the sun and melted the electronics, so I ordered a new one, but that didn't even turn on either. Since it's not the receiver, I guess it has to be the esc, but it seems fine. It beeps when I plug in the battery and the motor will twitch just barely, so I don't think there's a problem there.

I'm really confused now, what is going wrong?

[radio and first receiver link](https://www.banggood.com/JJRC-JJPRO-EM-16-2_4GHz-6CH-AFHDS-2A-Mode-2-RC-Transmitter-with-Receiver-Support-P175-for-RC-Drone-p-1724957.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN), [second receiver link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D35C6MQ), [esc and motor link](https://www.banggood.com/XXD-A2212-2200KV-2212-Brushless-Motor-+-6035-propeller-+-SG90-9g-Micro-Servo+2-+-30A-ESC-Combo-for-RC-Airplane-Fixed-wing-Helicopter-p-1669705.html?rmmds=buy&cur_warehouse=CN), [battery link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077FRCK89).

Comment: With the battery removed, does the motor spin smoothly by hand? You may feel regular small detents from the magnets, which is normal, but the rotation should be easy and even all the way around. Also, if you have a multimeter, check for power out of the ESC to the receiver - when the propeller was stopped, it could have burned out the ESC (perhaps partially - e.g. one motor winding.)

Comment: @Kralc, yes the motor spins well by hand. I don't have a multimeter at the moment but i'll test that when I get one.

Comment: I have a few questions. Can you verify that the new receiver is bound to the transmitter and that the channels are matched correctly? Does any light turn on in the receiver when you plug in the battery?

Comment: @JacobB, new receiver won't turn on with battery and esc which makes me think the esc is broken but it seems fine and beeps when i plug in a battery, so it is not bound yet. For old receiver a light would turn on but new receiver i have no idea but i think yes.

Comment: The light may only come one when the receiver links up to the transmitter. I wouldn't expect it to come on if it is not bound. The instructions should say what the light means.

Comment: If you power on with the bind plug in the receiver, does the light blink? Here's the manual:  https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1108232/Fly-Sky-Fs-I6.html?page=11#manual

Comment: Also, your launch wasn't too bad, although that is quite a tricky way to do it. There are a number of things that could have caused that crash, and it's hard to be certain. It looks like the model slowed down to the point where it stalled, and one wing stalled before the other. The model didn't accelerate like I would expect, so it may be under powered or you might not have given it enough throttle. You might have been able to save it if you were faster on the controls, it's hard to tell - but that a more advanced model than most beginners can handle.

Comment: Electric models often torque roll to the left after launch, and holding some right rudder for the first second or two can help. Also double check your ailerons aren't reversed: moving the stick to the right should bring the right aileron up.

Comment: @RobinBennett, the light on new receiver would not turn on, with or without bind plug. manual says LED should blink when connected to power even if not yet bound. Also yes the ailerons are inverted, I installed them the wrong way but oh well. there was no rudder at the time of maiden because something was weird with the receiver, but after 2nd flight I was going to switch aileron for rudder controls and then i realized the thing was broken. Now that I'm saying that out loud I feel pretty stupid for trying to fly inverted ailerons with no rudder :P

Comment: I think most people have crashed due to inverted controls at some point. You get all excited to fly and forget to check, until it causes a crash and then you always check!

Comment: Do you have any other batteries or power supplies you could use to check the receiver? The manual says it'll accept 4 to 6.5v
It is possible that the BEC part of the ESC broke, but that crash looked very gentle. About the only mistake you could have made is plugging it in wrong.

Comment: @RobinBennett, I only have the one esc and battery so no.

Comment: You could run it from one cell of your lipo, but you'd have to make a cable. A servo extension with one pin removed would work. USB power would work too, that's 5v.

Comment: Well done on the construction ! I have also swapped my servos in one build and have muddled up the three phase motor wires on occasion. Binding must have worked based on you doing two flights so I'd check the voltages on the wires going from the BEC to the receiver. Your model shop will have a slew of little testing tools for ESC's and servos and the folk there don't mind checking the odd thing if its a slow day. Also check the ESC/Reciever manuals as they provide handy information on setting the limits etc. some one activated the break on my ESC for example while jiggling the throttle about.